# How to get rid of e+02 and how to improve my code Matlab

Tags: matlab

The task was to make a mortgage calculator to work out the payments needed to pay of the loan using a for loop and binary search. This is my answer:

```
    r=input('please input your interest rate value:');

    Xmin=0;
    Xmax=5000;
    d(1)=50000;
    d(300)=20;
    while (d(300)<-0.001||d(300)>0.001)

    Xmid=0.5*(Xmin+Xmax);

    for m=2:300
      d(m)=((1+r/100)^(1/12))*d(m-1)-Xmid;
    end
    if(d(300)>0)
      Xmin=Xmid;
  end
  if (d(300)<0)
      Xmax=Xmid;
  end
end

fprintf('monthly payment value %d / n',Xmid)
%r
%Xmax
%Xmin
%Xmid
```

However my answer is showing for example "monthly payment value 3.470040e+02 / n>> mortage_repayment"

How can I get rid of the e+02 and is there anyway to improve or neaten up my code? Thank you!

Comment: [`formatspec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html?refresh=true#inputarg_formatSpec) :)

Comment: Ho, and avoid the space between '/' and 'n' !

Comment: @obchardon it should be `\n` even.

Comment: Did what you said but still coming up with the e+02 format. Need it just to say 347.00 :/ Not quite sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: `fprintf('monthly payment value %10.2f \n',Xmid)` but read the doc about formatspec, it's easy to understand how it work.

Comment: That's fantastic thank you its worked!! If I could bother you one more time and ask how I can put a £ sign in my answer :) Thank you so much!!

Comment: @MichaelShaw Use `char(163)` to insert the GBP pound sign in text: `fprintf('monthly payment value %s%10.2f\n',char(163),Xmid);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to write a non-integer number `Xmid`, but you specified that the number is an integer with `%d`.

You have two options:

A) If you are not interested in the fractional part of the number, replace the `fprintf` line with  `fprintf('monthly payment value %d \n',round(Xmid))`. adding the `round` function will round your value to the nearest integer. (you can also use `ceil` or `floor` to round upwards or downwards, respectively).

B) If you are interested in the fractional part, replace the `fprintf` line with  `fprintf('monthly payment value %.2f \n',Xmid)` Changing the `d` to `.2f` means that instead of writing an integer, a decimal number with up to two digits after the dot will written.